# How to make AppVeyor use different versions of Emacs?

Tags: windows, powershell, emacs, appveyor

I want to use different versions of Emacs. I think I have to do this with the build matrix feature. I have searched around and cannot find how it is done.

I am going to use Choco to install my packages. The default version is Emacs24. But Emacs25 is available via an unofficial package.

I want to install different versions of the same software and run simultaneous builds.

Here is a wishful attempt of what it would look like (this doesn't work by the way):

```
matrix:
  - emacs: "24"
  - emacs: "25"

install:
  - ps : switch($emacs){ "24" {choco install emacs} "25" {choco install emacs64} default {echo "Emacs install fail"}}
  - refreshenv

build_script:
  - some script
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emacs` is **environment** variable (**not local** one). Also YAML syntax require `environment` tag before `matrix`. You can always create configuration in UI and press `Export YAML` button if you are not sure. And finally not space between `ps` and `:`. Other than that config is good. Here is fixed one:

```
environment:
  matrix:
  - emacs: 24
  - emacs: 25

install:
  - ps: switch($env:emacs){ 24 {choco install emacs} 25 {choco install emacs64} default {echo "Emacs install fail"}}
  - refreshenv
```

Side note: I would recommend `throw "Emacs install fail"` instead of `echo`.